# Hybrid Connection keeps on disconnecting

Tags: azure-hybrid-connections

Seems like our hybrid connection to the server has been constantly disconnecting every month or two. What we usually do is disconnect/connect the connection to fix it. Do hybrid connections have auto-reconnect when this happens? And quite wondering since it's been constantly disconnecting every a month or two, would like to know where is the main problem happening.

Does activity logging in Azure provides an exception logging?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? same problem here.

Comment: @TylerJones I did not. I already left the company I was with and wasn't able to solve the problem here. It was also a hectic problem to solve because enabling logging takes a lot of space in the server so we have to manually delete it or disable it.

Comment: Hey, think we figured it out. Looks like our On_premise gateway was the issue. we changed it to a clustered gateway and haven't seen the issue since.

Comment: @TylerJones That's great news. Might put that in mind if ever I had a same problem in the future. Thanks!